# EPPlus pie chart datalable overlap issue

Tags: c#, epplus

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kX5f.png)  Here, I am trying to move the positions of data labels of pie chart created by EPPlus. Currently its overlapping for small numbers on piece of pie.

I have VS 2013 and EPPlus 5.1.2 version. This issue arise with the smaller numbers on piece of pie.

```
   ExcelPieChart consumableChart = (ExcelPieChart)worksheet6.Drawings.AddChart("UncommittedPieChart", eChartType.Pie);
                            ExcelRange r5, r6;

                            r5 = worksheet3.Cells[String.Concat(startColumnUncommitted, startIndexUncommitted.ToString(), ":", startColumnUncommitted, Convert.ToInt32(endIndexUncommitted + 1))];
                            r6 = worksheet3.Cells[String.Concat(endColumnUncommitted, startIndexUncommitted.ToString(), ":", endColumnUncommitted, Convert.ToInt32(endIndexUncommitted + 1))];
                            //consumableChart.Series.Add(r6, r5);
                            var serie = consumableChart.Series.Add(r6, r5);
                            consumableChart.Style = OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.Chart.eChartStyle.Style2;
                            consumableChart.Title.Text = String.Concat("Funds Uncommitted by FA5 ", System.Environment.NewLine, "$ ", worksheet3.Cells[(totalUncomRow + 1), 13].Text);
                            consumableChart.Legend.Remove();
                            consumableChart.SetPosition(5, 5, 5, 5);
                            consumableChart.SetSize(1080, 1080);
                           // consumableChart.DataLabel.Position = eLabelPosition.BestFit;

                            var pieSerie = (ExcelPieChartSerie)serie;
                            pieSerie.DataLabel.ShowValue = true;
                            pieSerie.DataLabel.ShowLeaderLines = true;
                            pieSerie.DataLabel.ShowCategory = true;
                            pieSerie.DataLabel.ShowPercent = true;
                            pieSerie.DataLabel.ShowSeriesName = true;
                            pieSerie.DataLabel.Position = eLabelPosition.BestFit;
```

I am expecting no overlap of the datalabels by using this code

`pieSerie.DataLabel.Position = eLabelPosition.BestFit;`

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This seems like a library formatting problem; It's not uncommon for graphing libraries to produce weird results at edge cases. Try other, more manual, label positioning, perhaps.

Comment: @jhaagsma What other ways do you mean? any hints please?

Comment: Well, I haven't used that particular graphing library, but try something that isn't "BestFit" ?

Comment: Thanks @jhaagsma, Now I am looking a way if the data is < 5% then hiding datalabels. Is there any specific property to for this?

Comment: I've never used the ExcelPieChart library; this might help though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.chart.applydatalabels?view=vsto-2017

Comment: Not something that is really possible in Epplus unfortunately  Epplus does not have an excel engine, it just create the raw xml in a zip fle.  The pie chart slices do not actually exist until Excel opens the file and generates them - and the labels with it.  It would be the same as creating the chart in excel directly - the labels will overlap and you would have to move them manually.  If you wanted to hide labels I think the best you could do is use VBA which can get messy.